# App Engine Standard (Python) vs. App Engine Flexible (Node.js) - Billing Clarifications

Tags: python, node.js, google-app-engine

I am currently running a python app on GCE (app engine standard) it's a small app only running under 1 instance - and when I load test it increases/decreases instance as needed and I get billed for usages. Fine and Dandy.

Now when it comes node.js as per documentation I am on beta version of app engine flexible (previously managed VM's - Thanks marketing). I created an app deployed it for the first time and it created 2 compute engine instance (1 CPU small 1.7G mem). As far as I can tell looking at the documentation. These 2 instance will be running even if there is no load? is it correct? So the app engine flexible has a minimum 2 instance deployment correct? In app engine standard I have days where I get charged nothing cos no one visited the app (I know it's not popular - that's another issue). But in case of nodejs/flexible I will be charged for those days? correct?

Thanks for clarification? hmm.. this gives a whole new meaning to the word "flexible"

Comment: I probably won't help you much but I'm curious, is the python app running all the time or only when a request comes in? I mean in case of node app it's running even if no request comes in and some resources are needed to keep the app running.

Comment: Python app - only when a request comes in. I don't want flexible !! I love my standard app engine... simple.